# Show button outside ng-repeat based on value inside

Tags: angularjs

I have a table with some `proposals`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="tp in proposals">
    <td>
        <span class="label label-warning" data-ng-show="tp.IsApproved == 0">Awaiting</span>
        <span class="label label-danger" data-ng-show="tp.IsApproved == 1">Rejected</span>
        <span class="label label-success" data-ng-show="tp.IsApproved == 2">Approved</span>
    </td>
    <td> [...] </td>
</tr>
```

Then after this table I want to have a button which only shows if there are no items in `proposals` with `IsApproved = 0`. (So either they all have status 1/2 or none exist)

```
<button ng-if="hasOpenProposal == false" data-ng-click="doStuff()">Create New</button>
```

I guess I could do some weird stuff with `ng-init` to set `hasOpenProposal` to true at the point it encounters a 0 value but what would be a practical/good way to solve this?

Comment: Use your controller and inside create a variable that will do what you want based on proposals prior to displaying data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<button ng-if="!hasOpenProposal()" data-ng-click="doStuff()">Create New</button>
```

and implement the `hasOpenProposal()` function in the controller:

```
$scope.hasOpenProposal = function() {
    return $scope.proposals.some(function(p) {
        return p.IsApproved === 0;
    });
};
```

Or compute this flag once when the list of proposals is loaded and store it in a scope attribute.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `.some` but it seems really appropriate in this case. Especially because I didn't want to iterate through the list a second time. (although that's probably what `.some` does under the hood). 

I had to modify a bit to make sure my proposals were loaded before etc but it works now.